# append settings.php during profile installation

Tags: configuration, installation-profiles

I would like to add lines to my settings.php during my custom installation. I'm using some `$conf['...']` to match external content to my drupal and i would like not to do this by modifying directly the file.
During my custom install i want to use the external content to have a fully operational website after running my script.

Do you have an idea how i can do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: _"I would like to add lines to my settings.php during my custom installation...i would like not to do this by modifying directly the file"_ You have an irreconcilable contradiction there. The only way to add lines to a file is by modifying it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it would be possible in a task with something like 'install_settings'.
Currently i'm copying the default.settings to a default, i append what i want with an echo and then run the site-install. It's not the best but it's the only way i found.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this post about [Collecting and writing configuration settings to setting.php from an install profile](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/collecting-and-writing-configuration-settings-settingphp-install-profile).

It describes how a custom task (via [`hook_install_tasks_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks_alter/7)) was injected into the installation profile to display a custom form and, upon submission, how [`drupal_rewrite_settings()`](http://api.drupal.org/drupal_rewrite_settings) can be used to inject the custom settings into **settings.php**.